# Find largest row in a matrix with numpy (row with highest length)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a massive array with rows and columns. Some rows are larger than others. I need to get the max length row, that is, the row that has the highest length. I wrote a simple function for this, but I wanted it to be as fas as possible, like numpy fast. Currently, it looks like this:

Example array:

```
values = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [10,11,12,13]
]

def values_max_width(values):
    max_width = 1
    for row in values:
        if len(row) > max_width:
            max_width = len(row)
    return max_width
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with numpy?

Comment: If you only want the maximum length you can always do `max(map(len, values))` in pure python. If you want the row corresponding to the maximum length use `values[np.fromiter(map(len, values), int).argmax()]`

Comment: Your rows are different lengths, so you wouldn't be able to put the full array into numpy as it doesn't support jagged arrays. You will not be able to achieve this purely using numpy. You will have to use python builtins for at least some portion of your workflow, and may as well stay there, to be honest.

Comment: Thanks, Mstaino. In the tests I did, comparing all the approaches I had, yours was the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [261]: values = [ 
     ...:     [1,2,3], 
     ...:     [4,5,6,7,8,9], 
     ...:     [10,11,12,13] 
     ...: ] 
     ...:                                                                       
In [262]:                                                                       
In [262]: values                                                                
Out[262]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
In [263]: def values_max_width(values): 
     ...:     max_width = 1 
     ...:     for row in values: 
     ...:         if len(row) > max_width: 
     ...:             max_width = len(row) 
     ...:     return max_width 
     ...:                                                                       
In [264]: values_max_width(values)                                              
Out[264]: 6
In [265]: [len(v) for v in values]                                              
Out[265]: [3, 6, 4]
In [266]: max([len(v) for v in values])                                         
Out[266]: 6
In [267]: np.max([len(v) for v in values])                                      
Out[267]: 6
```

Your loop and the list comprehension are similar in speed, `np.max` is much slower - it has to first turn the list into an array.

```
In [268]: timeit max([len(v) for v in values])                                  
656 ns ± 16.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [269]: timeit np.max([len(v) for v in values])                               
13.9 µs ± 181 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [271]: timeit values_max_width(values)                                       
555 ns ± 13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

If you are starting with a list, it's a good idea to thoroughly test the list implementation. `numpy` is fast when it is doing compiled array stuff, but creating an array from a list is time consuming.

Making an array directly from `values` isn't much help.  The result in a object dtype array:

```
In [272]: arr = np.array(values)                                                
In [273]: arr                                                                   
Out[273]: 
array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), list([10, 11, 12, 13])],
      dtype=object)
```

Math on such an array is hit-or-miss, and always slower than math on pure numeric arrays.  We can iterate on such an array, but that iteration is slower than on a list.

```
In [275]: values_max_width(arr)                                                 
Out[275]: 6
In [276]: timeit values_max_width(arr)                                          
1.3 µs ± 8.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you can make it faster. I've tried using np.max over the length of each item, but that will take even longer:

```
import numpy as np
import time

values = []
for k in range(100000):
    values.append(list(np.random.randint(100, size=np.random.randint(1000))))


def timeit(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        now = time.time()
        retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('{} took {:.5f}s'.format(func.__name__, time.time() - now))
        return retval
    return wrapper

@timeit
def values_max_width(values):
    max_width = 1
    for row in values:
        if len(row) > max_width:
            max_width = len(row)
    return max_width


@timeit
def value_max_width_len(values):
    return np.max([len(l) for l in values])


values_max_width(values)
value_max_width_len(values)
```

> values_max_width took 0.00598s
>
> value_max_width_len took 0.00994s

*** Edit ***

As @Mstaino suggested, using map does make this code faster:

```
@timeit
def value_max_width_len(values):
    return max(map(len, values))
```

> values_max_width took 0.00598s
>
> value_max_width_len took 0.00499s

Comment: I understand, and thanks for the effort. The most optimized I've got so far was with `map` according to @Mstaino commend.

Comment: `np.max` is slower than Python `max` - because it first has to turn the list into an array.